# Returning all data types for a table in SOQL

Tags: postgresql, salesforce, soql

Is there a simple way to query and return a list of datatypes for all columns in a SOQL table?

I'm trying to migrate SOQL to PostgreSQL but have 100s of tables and 100s of columns and don't want to go through querying every data type or doing it by hand.

In PostgreSQL the equivalent to what I'm looking for would be:

```
SELECT table_name, data_type, columns.character_maximum_length, columns.udt_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

Looking around it looks like I might have to go into Apex? But I'm wondering if there's any simpler way. I don't think that SOQL supports `information_schema` and can't find if there's a simlar

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to introspect schema in SOQL itself. While you can interact with the Describe API via Apex, it's easier as an external API client to do so via the Salesforce REST API.

Specifically, you'd want to hit the [Global Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_describeGlobal.htm) endpoint to get the list of available sObjects.

The, for each sObject, hit [sObject Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm). The response body includes [field details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm) for that sObject under the `fields` key. The field's type is given in each `fields` entry as both `type`, which is a high-level UI-oriented type (see [`DisplayType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm) enum), and as the lower-level [`soapType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_SOAPType.htm), which is usually more relevant for database storage and API interaction.

Note that in both cases the API will enforce FLS and CRUD based on the authenticated user account's credentials. If a logged-in user with those credentials doesn't have permission to see an object or field, neither will your external application.